# wpf control template

Tags: wpf, templates, controls, controltemplate

I have a very simple case that I think would benefit from using templates (but I'm not sure, which is why I'm asking).  All the templating examples I've seen either assume more knowledge than I have, are too specific to be of much use to a total newb like myself, or contain lots of ancillary stuff that makes it hard to identify what's part of the template.

Here's the setup: 
I have two labels side-by-side, with the first label populated with the name of a field, and the second label populated with the value of the field.

Here is the XAML I currently have in my app (many, many times):

```
<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource horizontalStackerStyle}">
    <Label Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}">Field One:</Label>
    <Label Style="{StaticResource valueStyle}" Name="field1" 
        Content="{Binding dataObject.field1}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I would like to create a template such that I could write XAML like this:

```
<CustomControlOrWhatever 
    FieldName="Field One:" 
    FieldValue="{Binding dataObject.field1}"/>
```

I have a feeling I can do this with some kind of template.  One benefit of which would be that I don't need to keep specifying the styles over and over.  Am I correct?  How would I do this?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Still haven't found an answer to this.  I chose a possible solution using Dependency Properties, and tried to ask a [clarifying question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145435/wpf-trouble-using-dependency-properties-in-a-usercontrol/1145485#1145485).  Well, the first responder said that I don't actually need to clutter up my code behind with DP nonsense, so I changed it again--and it still doesn't work.  Can anyone come up with a working solution?  This seems like it should be so simple.

Just to be clear: this only needs to be one-way binding with values updated every few seconds.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, since you asked a separate question, why unmark this one?

Comment: Because I'm a total newb and have very little experience with this system.  I assume that you check the answer that helped you the most, or that best answered the question.

Simply put: I couldn't get your solution to work.  As I have no way of knowing whether the problem is with your solution or (more likely) with my implementation of it, I chose to uncheck it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is basically a user control.

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="SomeNameSpace.SomeControlName">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
     <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource horizontalStackerStyle}">
      <Label Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}" x:Name="FieldNameLbl"></Label>
      <Label Style="{StaticResource valueStyle}" x:Name="ValueLbl">
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the code behind, you'd need to expose two properties that would set the value of the controls.

```
public string FieldName
{
    get { return FieldNameLbl.Text; }
    set { FieldNameLbl.Text = value; }
}

public string FieldValue
{
    get { return ValueLbl.Text; }
    set { ValueLbl.Text = value; }
}
```

And then to call that you can put this at the top of your window/page with the rest of your declarations:

```
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:SomeNameSpace"
```

and then you can insert the control into your window/page like this:

```
<Controls:NameOfYourControl FieldName="Field One:" FieldValue="{Binding dataObject.field1}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response!

Comment: +1, sometimes nice to make the CLR properties dependency properties.

Comment: It's apparently totally necessary to make these dependency properties.  This field is updated every few seconds with values from a serial port connection.  So I'm trying to bind the fieldValue to a property on my business object, but I can't seem to get the dependency property stuff to work.

Is this the appropriate way to ask follow up questions, or do I need to start a new question?

Comment: I would start a new question. Your original question was how to make a tmeplate, which is answered by my response.

Continuously updating a DP warrants a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `UserControl` called `FieldControl` and define backing (automatic) properties for `FieldName` and `FieldValue`. (Normal properties would be fine, so long as you only need to bind once, which is probably the case.)

The XAML code might look like:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Class="foo.bar">
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource horizontalStackerStyle}">
        <Label Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}" Content="{Binding Path=FieldName, Mode=OneTime, StringFormat='{0}: '}"/>
        <Label Style="{StaticResource valueStyle}" Content="{Binding Path=FieldValue, Mode=OneTime}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough reputation for an up vote.

But to more thoroughly answer you:

It helped me see the form of the XAML, which is a start.  But I'm discovering that to make this UserControl useful, I need to set up dependency properties and figure out how to bind everything.  So far, no luck.

Comment: Klay: Sorry, my bad - I forget these things at my rep! Well I'm glad it's helped you understand things at least. +1 to your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is similar to the discussion about putting images on a button with a simple way of specifying the path, like `<Button MyImage="foo.jpg" />`. Follow **[this article](http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/01/create-wpf-image-button-through-attached-properties)** for the actual details.

To summarize:

- One obvious way would be to create an UserControl containing your two labels and exposing the two properties. Not much templating here.
- The most WPFish solution seems to be to use two Attached Properties on one of the labels (say the value), and provide a control template for it that includes the other label (the description). In the template, you bind each label text to the corresponding attached property value.